# How to cycle through many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code.

```
Sub Journal()
    Dim ColL As Range, ColC  As Range
    Dim ws120 As Worksheet: Set ws120 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("120")
    Dim ws121 As Worksheet: Set ws121 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("121")
    Dim ws122 As Worksheet: Set ws122 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("122")
    Dim ws123 As Worksheet: Set ws123 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("123")
    Dim ws124 As Worksheet: Set ws124 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("124")
    Dim ws125 As Worksheet: Set ws125 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("125")
    Dim ws126 As Worksheet: Set ws126 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("126")
    Dim ws127 As Worksheet: Set ws127 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("127")
    Dim ws128 As Worksheet: Set ws128 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("128")
    Dim ws220 As Worksheet: Set ws220 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("220")
    Dim ws221 As Worksheet: Set ws221 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("221")
    Dim ws402 As Worksheet: Set ws402 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("402")
    Dim ws403 As Worksheet: Set ws403 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("403")
    Dim wsLoc As Worksheet: Set wsLoc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locker JE")
    Dim wsCof As Worksheet: Set wsCof = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coffee JE")
    Dim Eval, rw As Range
    Dim i As Long '<< use long in place on Integer

    With wsLoc
        Set ColL = .Cells(4, "O")
    End With
    With wsCof
        Set ColC = .Cells(4, "O")
    End With

    For i = 4 To 41
        Set rw = ws120.Rows(i)
        Temp = rw.Cells(31).Value
        Select Case rw.Cells(31).Value
            Case ""
            Case Else
                CopyLocker rw, ColL
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am wanting to do the same thing in the for next loop for each of the defined worksheets.  Is this possible with a variable of some sort?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: I didn't want to go through all the worksheets.  I had found that but it didn't work for what I needed.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring all of those as worksheets, an option would be to load them into an array, then loop through the array.

This isn't exactly your macro, but it shows how you can use a loop through an array to do what you're looking for:

```
Sub Journal()
Dim wsArray() As Variant
Dim k As Long, i As Long
Dim rw As Range, ColL As Range
Dim TempCel As Range
Dim wsLoc   As Worksheet: Set wsLoc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locker JE")
Dim wsCof   As Worksheet: Set wsCof = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coffee JE")

wsArray = Array("120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "220", "221", "402", "403", "Locker JE", "Coffee JE")
Set ColL = wsLoc.Cells(4, "O")
Set ColC = wsCof.Cells(4, "O")

For k = LBound(wsArray) To UBound(wsArray)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsArray(k))
        ' Do things with the worksheet.
        For i = 4 To 41
            Set rw = .Rows(i)
            Set TempCel = rw.Cells(31)
            Select Case TempCel.Value
                Case ""
                     ' Do something...
                Case Else
                    CopyLocker rw, ColL
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Note: This all assumed that you have other worksheets in the workbook you *don't* want this run on.  Otherwise, you can just do `For each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and skip the whole array thing.

Comment: This looks like it will do exactly what I need.  I will try it out and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: @BSumner - Do you have a bunch of other sheets in there? If you have say 3 sheets (or any number *less* than the amount in that array), you can do another way...`For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets // if ws.Name <> "999" and ws.Name <> "000" Then ...`.

Comment: That worked so much faster than I expected.  Thanks so much.

Comment: (@BSumner - You're very welcome! If it worked for you, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows)